# Recursive function reading old values from last recursive iteration

Tags: c#, recursion

This code snippet reads the input from console and returns an object. 
If there are any errors it calls itself again.

I have validation rule to check if input values are not letters. And my Validator is returning that error and calling this function again to take correct input.

The problem with below code is that:

- When I give incorrect input, let's say "abc".
- Validator returns error and print that out on console and asks for
  new input.
- Now, when I submit the correct input, say 12, it throws a
  FormatException during parsing the char Array. line :
  `Int32.Parse(positionXY[0].ToString())`

How can I fix it ?

```
public MissileCoordinates ReadCoordinates()
{
    PrintLine($"Enter Coordinates", ConsoleColor.White);
    var move = Console.ReadLine();
    List<string> errors = constraintValidator.ValidateMissile(move).ToList();

    if (errors.Any())
    {
        foreach (var error in errors)
        {
            PrintLine(error, ConsoleColor.White);
        }
        ReadCoordinates();
    }
    else
    {
        var positionXY = move.ToCharArray();

        return new MissileCoordinates
        {
            PosX = Int32.Parse(positionXY[0].ToString()),
            PosY = Int32.Parse(positionXY[1].ToString())
        };
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I used your code to create a fiddle and it runs fine https://dotnetfiddle.net/0IDn6Y
can you post full code and the input example you are trying to give

Comment: This method is a bad candidate for recursion in the first place. It would be far more appropriate to use a `do` or `while` loop to read the input.

Comment: I agree with @jmcilhinney

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recursive function should be:

```
public MissileCoordinates ReadCoordinates()
{
    PrintLine($"Enter Coordinates", ConsoleColor.White);
    var move = Console.ReadLine();
    List<string> errors = constraintValidator.ValidateMissile(move).ToList();

    if (errors.Any())
    {
        foreach (var error in errors)
        {
            PrintLine(error, ConsoleColor.White);
        }
        return ReadCoordinates();
    }
    else
    {
        var positionXY = move.ToCharArray();

        return new MissileCoordinates
        {
            PosX = Int32.Parse(positionXY[0].ToString()),
            PosY = Int32.Parse(positionXY[1].ToString())
        };
    }
}
```

here's the fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/kbrP4u

Comment: damn the return keyword. :D